# Compiler Error Message: CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request

Tags: javascript, c#, css

I'm working with ASP.MVC4 . i have bulid and published same files in different ports one port is working fine but other port i'm getting the below error page please any one can suggest for solution for ..

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 42:          Line 43:         public override void Execute() {
>   Line 44:
>   WriteLiteral("\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"
>   + Line 45: "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"
>   + Line 46: "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"
>   +
>
> Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\fe78b6c6\eaadfefd\App_Web_index.cshtml.364523cc.s_uuxf94.0.cs
>   Line: 44

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to `WriteLiteral(@"\\\\\\\\\\\\\" + @"\\\\\\\\\" + ...`

Comment: thanks for response but here i'm not writing that block of code  it's auto generating i'm unable find that where it's getting while running solution  can suggest any solution to how to find it

Comment: i'm getting like below in Show Complete Compilation Source:
Line 3:    // <auto-generated>
Line 4:    //     This code was generated by a tool.
Line 5:    //     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.34209
Line 6:    //
Line 7:    //     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
Line 8:    //     the code is regenerated.
Line 9:    // </auto-generated>

Comment: ok, sorry I did not realize that it was generated code. I'm not familiar with what is doing the generating...

Comment: i have small doubt here i'm using same published build in both ports on same server  but it's working fine in one port  ,other port i'm getting error like so

Comment: You need to find what is causing this code to be generated. Possibly it is being generated differently on the two servers for some reason. Search your code or data files or database for a bunch of backslashes to try to find it.